# Force load SVG file without or wrong MIME type with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I know the correct way is for the server to return `Content-Type: image/svg+xml` in the HTTP header when fetching SVG.

Would there be a workaround for fetching and displaying the SVG image even if the Content-Type is not set or set incorrectly with Javascript or even HTML or CSS?

Comment: Browsers don't do that because it leads to security holes. You could try to work around that at your own risk by loading the data via an XMLHttpRequest